# Overloading methods in Kotlin generates the next error Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature

Tags: kotlin, overloading

Hello I have defined two methods in Kotlin, my idea is overload the methods and get different kind of arguments.

The next are my methods:

```
private fun methodOverloaded(singleList: List<Tool>, mkUrl: String?, commentStyle: String, resultsPageUri: String?, githubCommentExperiment: String){

}

private fun methodOverloaded(singleList: List<GroupedTool>, mkUrl: String?, commentStyle: String, resultsPageUri: String?, githubCommentExperiment: String){

}
```

I have two methods with an argument of type `List<Tool>` and another one `List<GroupedTool>` but the JVM sends the error saying that the dataTypes are the same, even though they are different types of List, not sure if that is possible to do in Kotlin or Java.

Any ideas?

Comment: They are not "different" types of lists.  They are the same type, but hold different values.  This might differentiate them to you, it does not differentiate them to the compiler.  You might want to read up on how collections hold generics, to come up with a better answer.

BTW - it would probably be more usable to specify different method names if the methods take different types of arguments.

Comment: Is not a child of Tool

Comment: `List<Tool>` and `List<GroupedTool>` can't be differentiated because of [type erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-erasure)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this just fine in Kotlin with an annotation.

```
@JvmName("toolListMethod")
private fun methodOverloaded(singleList: List<Tool>, mkUrl: String?, commentStyle: String, resultsPageUri: String?, githubCommentExperiment: String){

}
@JvmName("groupedToolListMethod")
private fun methodOverloaded(singleList: List<GroupedTool>, mkUrl: String?, commentStyle: String, resultsPageUri: String?, githubCommentExperiment: String){

}
```

Only the JVM, not Kotlin, has a problem with the conflicting erasures.